# Consuming a Web Service from PL/SQL in Oracle 11g, speed

Tags: oracle, performance, web-services, rest

I'm using utl_http package to call a web service. It is an internal web service, and can be called in a REST way. The response time is about 0.04s with PL/SQL. I will have to loop through millions of records. I wonder what can be done to make it run faster? Either certain configurations in Oracle, some setup for the package or connection, or anything...?

```
L_Baseurl    := 'http://192.168.136.58/...';
L_Param_List := '...';
L_Url           := Utl_Url.Escape(L_Baseurl||'?'||L_Param_List);
L_Http_Request  := Utl_Http.Begin_Request (L_Url);
L_Http_Response := Utl_Http.Get_Response(L_Http_Request);
...
Utl_Http.End_Response(L_Http_Response);
```

I've tried to set persistent connection, but it doesn't seem to help much. Doing it asynchronously? I am pretty new to Oracle and consuming web services, any suggestions would help. Thanks!